# How to control with CSS width of images parent element

Tags: css, width, fluid-layout

in a fluid design layout I would like to scale images so that all of them had same height but could have varying width depending on image aspect ratio. Also, all images sit within an anchor tag. In Mozilla browser i get a problem where width of anchor tag doesn't adjust automatically. For instance, if image would have dimensions 200x100px and height of anchor tag would be 50px then in Mozilla the anchor tag would have dimensions 200x50px, and not 100x50px as I want. What should my CSS be in order to fix this? Thank you

My HTML is:

```
<a class="testimage"><img src="sliderimages/picture8.jpg"/></a>
```

CSS is:

```
<style>  
    .testimage {height:10%;display:inline-block;border:1px solid yellow;}
    .testimage img {height:100%;}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you include an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Please also post the image here.. (or same proportion any other image)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some simple calculations with JavaScript. Here's a simple HTML page with JavaScript for you to modify and test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Set Image Height
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <img src='testimage1.jpg' onload='setImageHeight()'>
    <img src='testimage2.png' onload='setImageHeight()'>

    <script>
        function setImageHeight(event) {
            // Allow for cross-platform differences
            event = event || this.event;
            element = event.target || event.srcElement;

            var temp = new Image(),
                fixedHeight = 50,
                height, width, scaledWidth;

            temp.src = element.src;
            width = temp.width;
            height = temp.height;
            scaledWidth = width * fixedHeight / height;

            element.style.width = scaledWidth + "px";
            element.style.height = fixedHeight + "px";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an [example](http://dev.lexogram.com/tests/imageHeight/index.html).

Comment: Hi James, i want to figure out how to do this in CSS. Javascript is not an option in this case

Comment: CSS is not a programming language. It does not allow you to make any calculations. I can think of three alternatives. (1) You roll the CSS by hand for each image according to its dimensions (2) You generate the CSS style declarations on the fly using PHP or some other server-side code (3) You generate (thumbnail) images for display on the fly so that they are already the size at which you want them to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .... 
set .testimage to `display: block;`
To specify the height or width of a tag you should apply display to block not inline-block.
Hope this works.